# Responsive JSF datatable (Problemas con ser responsivo)

Tags: jsf, primefaces

verán quisiera hacer responsive mi aplicacion estoy usando el tipo reflow de Primefaces, la parte de la tabla queda algo así:

```
            <p:commandLink  oncomplete="PF('confirmActivateWdg').show();return false;" partialSubmit="true" immediate="true" process="@this" update="msjSesion" rendered="#{admPersonaMB.canCloseSession and per.estado ne 'A'}">
                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{per}" target="#{admPersonaMB.selectedClient}"  />
                <b:iconAwesome name="thumbs-up" tooltip="#{msg['cliente.activar.tooltip']}" styleClass="icon-accion-green" ></b:iconAwesome>
            </p:commandLink>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <p:commandLink  oncomplete="PF('confirmDeleteSesionWdg').show();return false;" partialSubmit="true" immediate="true" process="@this" update="msjSesion" rendered="#{admPersonaMB.canCloseSession and per.accountVerified eq true}">
                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{per}" target="#{admPersonaMB.selectedClient}"  />
                <b:iconAwesome name="power-off" tooltip="#{msg['cliente.cerrarsesion.tooltip']}" styleClass="icon-accion" ></b:iconAwesome>
            </p:commandLink>                
            <p:commandLink  oncomplete="PF('confirmDeleteWdg').show();return false;" partialSubmit="true" immediate="true" process="@this" update="msjSesion" rendered="#{admPersonaMB.canCloseSession and per.accountVerified eq false}">
                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{per}" target="#{admPersonaMB.selectedClient}"  />
                <b:iconAwesome name="trash" tooltip="#{msg['cliente.eliminar.tooltip']}" styleClass="icon-accion-red" ></b:iconAwesome>
            </p:commandLink>
        </p:column> 
    </p:dataTable>
```

El problema es que no sale de manera responsive

Comment: Hola, podrías agregar el código completo del data table por favor

Answer (score 0):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así sale la imagen, alguien podría ayudarme?